# com.lowagie.text.ExceptionConverter: Can't create cache file (in the read-only docker container)

Tags: java, docker, exception, pdf

When running in the read-only docker container, the following line

```
Image.getInstance(logoUrl);
```

throwed the exception

```
2023-10-19 13:55:28.507 ERROR 1 --- [qtp795321555-23] c.r.c.b.a.error.GeneralExceptionMapper   : Request failed with exception: Can't create cache file! class com.lowagie.text.ExceptionConverter
com.lowagie.text.ExceptionConverter: Can't create cache file!
```

The thing is: the exception is only thrown for the png-file, and the jpg-files work correctly.

Do you have any idea, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
The thing is, Image.getInstance() has different branches to parse different file contents, for example:

```
 if (c1 == 71 && c2 == 73 && c3 == 70) {
            var14 = ImageLoader.getGifImage(imgb);
            return var14;
        }

        if (c1 == 255 && c2 == 216) {
            var14 = ImageLoader.getJpegImage(imgb);
            return var14;
        }

        if (c1 == 0 && c2 == 0 && c3 == 0 && c4 == 12) {
            var14 = ImageLoader.getJpeg2000Image(imgb);
            return var14;
        }

        if (c1 == 255 && c2 == 79 && c3 == 255 && c4 == 81) {
            var14 = ImageLoader.getJpeg2000Image(imgb);
            return var14;
        }

        if (c1 == PNGID[0] && c2 == PNGID[1] && c3 == PNGID[2] && c4 == PNGID[3]) {
            var14 = ImageLoader.getPngImage(imgb);
            return var14;
        }
```

so, if the processing of jpeg files works correctly, we need to convert input formats to jpeg:
InputStream is = logoUrl.openStream();
ImageIO.setUseCache(false);

```
            var bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(is);
            var convertedImage = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            convertedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            var canWrite = ImageIO.write(convertedImage, "jpg", outputStream);
            if (canWrite) {
                logoImage = Image.getInstance(outputStream.toByteArray());
            }
```

From one hand, such solution has a negative side as conversion of each file to jpg, but from another side, everything works and (if required) it's possible to refactor the solution to apply conversion to png file only.